# String replace with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I currently have this `sed` command that replaces `foo.us.param=value` with `foo.param=value`:

```
sed -i -e 's/\.us\./\./p' file.txt
```

Problem is that it creates a duplicate of each line it matches. If I add a `-n` it deletes all lines that don't match the regex.

How can I fix it to leave the lines that don't match and only output the line it edits once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `p` flag that makes `sed` print the line again upon successful replacement:

```
sed -i 's/\.us\./\./' file.txt
```